# VBA to swap row range ignoring cells with formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code to swap two row ranges (excluding column A) but need it to ignore cells that contain a formula (in this case columns K&L).  The code I have below works fine but messes up the formulas in columns K&L!  Can  anyone advise how best to overcome this?

```
Sub swap()
    If Selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Set range1 = Selection.Areas(1)
    Set range2 = Selection.Areas(2)


    Set range1 = range1.Resize(, 100)
    Set range2 = range2.Resize(, 100)

     If range1.Rows.Count <> range2.Rows.Count Or _
        range1.Columns.Count <> range2.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub

    range1Address = range1.Address
    range1.Cut
    range2.Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
    Range(range1Address).Delete shift:=xlToLeft

    range2Address = range2.Address
    range2.Cut
    Range(range1Address).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
    Range(range2Address).Delete shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you just want to copy and "paste values"?

Comment: Are the two ranges the same exact size with formulas in corresponding places? If not, the requirements are unclear. Also, when you move cells to which formulas refer, are the references in the formulas supposed to change, or are they still to refer to the original cells? What exactly do you mean by "messes up" the formulas? What would non-messed-up formulas look like?

Comment: The two ranges are the same size with formulas in corresponding emails and I need the references in the formulas to change.  By retaining their reference to the original cells is what was causing an issue.  The "messes up" just means they kept their original cell reference and I needed it to change to correspond with the row number that swapped to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to swap their locations, use only the column #s to make it a little easier:

```
Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long
If Selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub
col1 = Selection.Areas(1).Column
col2 = Selection.Areas(2).Column
If Left(Cells(2, col1), 1) = "=" Or Left(Cells(2, col2), 1) = "=" Then Exit Sub 'Should catch if it's a formula
Columns(col1).Cut
Columns(col2).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
Columns(col2).Cut
Columns(col1).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
```

Having put formulas into some cells that were being moved, i did not have any issues (simple addition of all cells in the range, 1 by 1, not sum()).  The reference locations of the cells in the formula changed to the corresponding new locations and as such didn't change the output of the formula.

You may have run into issues because you deleted values, which could remove references.

Comment: I used only columns thinking that your omission of specific columns justified the usage.